# Is there a way to make a nested list validate?

Tags: html, w3c-validation

This list seems to give an error when trying to use w3c validator:

```
<ul class="navtest" >
    <ul>
        <li><a href="url.php">Fall Catalog</a></li>
        <li><a href="url.php">Contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

The error I get is: Line 94, Column 12: start tag for "LI" omitted, but its declaration does not permit this

```
        <ul>
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? Using: HTML 4.01 Transitional

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<ul class="navtest" >
<li>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="url.php">Fall Catalog</a></li>
        <li><a href="url.php">Contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

missing li's

Comment: Thanks, Kind of screws up my css now. needa fix it.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/lists.html#edef-UL), the only element that a `UL` may contain is one or more `LI` elements.

See the DTD fragment:

```
<!ELEMENT UL - - (LI)+                 -- unordered list -->
```

You can put the *second* list within a list item:

```
<ul class="navtest" >
  <li>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="url.php">Fall Catalog</a></li>
        <li><a href="url.php">Contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you're simply not allowed to put a `<ul>` inside another `<ul>` without nesting it inside a `<li>`.

My question to you is: why are you using a standard from 99?

Comment: DO you mean my doctype selection? Why is it from 99?

Comment: HTML 4.01 Transitional is from 99, yes.

Answer (score 1):

The above have answered your question. This link will give you more details why this issue generated in the validator:

https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/52a217227c82ca0e9b000c21

The only input a UL element can take is an LI element. Since you can insert a UL element in the LI element, you must place the closing LI tag **after** the nested UL/LI cluster. Otherwise you are just nesting a UL within a UL, which isn't allowed.

TL/DR: Nest the UL/LI inside of the LI, not the UL.